# How can I automate the creation of a new branch from the main branch and to do the changes in the new branch from another branch in Git?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have a Gitlab pipeline and my CICD is taken care of by the Gitlab runners. I have a feature branch say for example feat_1 and for a particular use case, I need to implement this functionality in this feature branch.
->Whenever I trigger this feature branch, it should create a new branch from the main branch of the same repository and it should update a file in the newly created branch and push the changes to the newly created branch so that the deployment related to those changes will happen in the auto trigger of the new branch.

Comment: Are you asking for the command to create a new branch? The way I read this question, when the trigger runs, it runs a script, which does: 0.) Fetch (maybe), 1.) Create a branch. 2.) Modify a file. 3.) Commit and push. Is that what you're asking? Side note, it doesn't seem like the new branch has any relation to `feat_1`, so I'm not sure really sure what the point of `feat_1` is, except to trigger the script?

Comment: @TTT Yes, the purpose of feat_1 is to create a new branch and keep the logic that to be applied on some of the files in the new branch and push the new branch so that the new branch created will trigger a pipeline.  Is there any way I can achieve this? Also I need to create a schedule on the feat_1 branch There are some dependencies in my pipelines that is the reason I am trying to opt this approach